# parse xml and copy it to new file?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I need to parse a big xml file and have my code generate a new xml file with the elements I need from the original file. How would you do this? A lot of the time I will be copying the code, sometimes editing and inserting my own code.  what modules are there to make my life easier? What if I wanted to parse all this stuff, copy to a new file but change the action tag etc, is this stuff easily done in python?

```
<COMMAND name="interface range"
        help="Apply commands to a range of ports"
        view="configure-range-view"
        viewid="iface-range">
        <PARAM name="interface_method"
           help="Method to get interface information"
           optional="false"
           ptype="SUBCOMMAND"
           mode="switch">
           <PARAM name="FastEthernet"
                  help="FastEthernet IEEE 802.3"
                  ptype="SUBCOMMAND"
                  mode="subcommand">
                  <PARAM name="iface_num"
                         help="FastEthernet interface number"
                         ptype="IFACE_NUM">            
                  </PARAM>
           </PARAM>
           <PARAM name="GigabitEthernet"
                  help="GigabitEthernet IEEE 802.3z"
                  ptype="SUBCOMMAND"
                  mode="subcommand">
                  <PARAM name="iface_num"
                         help="GigabitEthernet interface number"
                         ptype="GIGETH_NUM">
                  </PARAM>      
           </PARAM>

        </PARAM>

        <ACTION>
        /path/to-scripts/script.py
        </ACTION>
</COMMAND>
```

This is the page I am using which lists the libraries, wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml I'm not looking for labour/code etc, I wish to do this myself, I'm looking for peoples experience on the matter, I was wondering perhaps is there a form of standard one that everybody uses, such as ElementTree. I have read other posts on here asking the same question, but they are old.

Comment: what does your first attempt look like? where did your first google search for python xml lead you?

Comment: @rectummelancolique I got ElementTree from pythonxml, but there are a lot of different libraries and such, so I want to know from peoples experience what they use and why they think it is good, does it do what I want, what are the limitations etc

Comment: Then explicitely cite what libraries you have considered, the code you've written using them, and what you dislike with using these. As it is your question looks like you've made no effort at all and that you're after free labour.

Comment: @rectummelancolique This is the page I am using which lists the libraries, http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml I'm not looking for labour/code etc, I wish to do this myself, I'm looking for peoples experience on the matter, I was wondering perhaps is there a form of standard one that everybody uses, such as ElementTree. I have read other posts on here asking the same question, but they are old.

Comment: [lxml](http://lxml.de/) is a viable option. It can [handle large XML files](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-hiperfparse/). Check out the example on "serialization" for an example of how to rewrite XML.

Comment: @unutbu Great thanks, will have a look at the examples for that.

Comment: Then say it explicitly, edit this in your question, not here in the comments. "How would you do this?" is very vague, and you are bound to attract reactions such as mine, and probably very few ansers.

Comment: @rectummelancolique edited in my last comment thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar situation. I used the **xml.etree.ElementTree** and **copy** modules to parse and replicate XML. I have used **shallow copy** by default. You may use **deepcopy** instead.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import copy

tree = ET.parse("SourceFile.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

command = ET.Element("COMMAND")

for param in root.iter('COMMAND'):
    condition:
        paramscopy = copy.copy(param)
        command.append(paramscopy)

btree = ET.ElementTree(command)
btree.write("NewFile.xml")
```